# Spring Boot project with Neo4J and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, neo4j

I have a Spring Boot project with Neo4J and MongoDB as DBs.

The project was deployed in production a few months ago and it's working very well.
Reviewing the code I realised that it doesn't have MongoDB configured properly because we started working with Neo4J and added MongoDB support later.

The project had the configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.name.project.dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jAuditing
@EnableAsync
```

As you can see, the configuration doesn't have anything related to MongoDB but the project and its tests are working.

The problem comes when I wanted to add the MongoDB configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.name.project.dao.neo4j")
@EnableNeo4jAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.name.project.dao.mongo")
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableAsync
```

Note, I split the repositories into two different packages (just in case...)
Again the project and almost all [integration] tests are working great but the tests with the annotation `@DataNeo4jTest` are failing in the context load.

```
A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.
```

I tried to add `@DataMongoTest` but it's failing because multiple `@BootstrapWith` annotations are not possible.

How can I configure Neo4J + MongoDB project and its tests to work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: Move all the annotations to a dedicated configuration class. If not spirng boot is not able to disable parts of it due to all the `@ENable*` annotations on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, leading to things like this.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226267/using-spring-data-mongodb-and-spring-data-neo4j-together

Comment: I followed the @M.Deinum indications and it worked! Thanks!